# Meteor Spacebars if else BREAKS semantic-ui accordion

Tags: jquery, meteor, semantic-ui, spacebars

I have perfectly working semantic-ui accordion.

But when I put it inside a spacebars if else statement then suddenly it will not work.

```
{{#if}}
//accordion code

{{else}}

{{/if}}
```

What is the reason for this and what is a work around for this?

Thank you

Comment: Try those comments http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/#comments

Comment: I'd guess you need to re-initialize the accordion (`$(...).accordion()`) after it disappears and reappears. Try putting the accordion in its own template, then in that template's `onRendered` do `this.$(".ui.accordion").accordion()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Materialize: dropdown in "if" statement doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815310/materialize-dropdown-in-if-statement-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

The comment from  user3374348
solved it...

"I'd guess you need to re-initialize the accordion ($(...).accordion()) after it disappears and reappears. Try putting the accordion in its own template, then in that template's onRendered do this.$(".ui.accordion").accordion() –  user3374348 yesterday"