# Materialize Dropdown weird behavior when using with React if-else syntax

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu, reactjs, materialize

I am using MaterializeCSS and React to render a simple dropdown based on whether the user is logged in or not.
The idea is that if the user is logged in, to show the dropdown menu and if they are not, to only show a logout link.

```
<nav className="transparent black-text" role="navigation">
  <ul id="dropdown" className="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="/#">My Profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="/#">My Documents</a></li>
    <li className="divider"></li>
    <li>
      <a href="/#"> Logout
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div className="nav-wrapper container">
    <a className="brand-logo brand-logo-small" href="/">
      <img alt="Logo" id="header-logo" src="../../images/favicon.png"/>
      {'My Document'}
    </a>
    <ul className="right hide-on-med-and-down" id="nav-mobile">
      <li>
        {this.state.loggedIn == 'true'
          ? <a className="dropdown-button"
                  data-activates="dropdown"
                  data-beloworigin="true"
                  data-constrainwidth="false"
                  href="/#">{'User'}
            <i className="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
            </a>
          : <a href="/auth">Login</a>
        }
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

In the above snippet, if the loggedIn flag equals `true`, I expect that the dropdown should be displayed, but it isn't.
However, when I add `className="dropdown-button" data-activates="dropdown"` attributes to the second `<a>` tag, the dropdown gets displayed.
Additionally, if I remove the `className="dropdown-button" data-activates="dropdown"` attributes from the first link, the dropdown is still displayed.

What could I be doing wrong here? Why is the dropdown on the first `<a>` tag only displayed when I set the attributes on the second `<a>` tag?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `this.state.loggedIn` a string or a boolean? You're comparing it to the string, but it probably should be a boolean.

Comment: I'd also recommend using React DevTools to look into this, as you can see which element is actually being rendered and why. Breaking that part of the code into its own `<UserDropdown>` component might also help.

Comment: The `loggedIn` state is actually a string, so that part is hopefully not the problem. I also used React DevTools, but maybe I'll take another look.
Thanks for helping out.

Comment: I have this problem too! Hoping a ReactJS expert can weigh in. Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815310/materialize-dropdown-in-if-statement-doesnt-work) the same?